# How to Segue from a AVPlayer recording to a new Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, segue, swift4

I have this Delegate in my CameraViewController. It calls fileOutput when its done capturing a video. I want to pass the url of the captured video to my next view controller in my storyboard where I show the captured file:

```
extension CameraViewController: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate{
    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        let destinationVC = PreviewViewController()
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error recording movie: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            let videoRecorded = outputURL! as URL
        }
        outputURL = nil    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if segue.identifier == "showCapture_Segue" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! CameraPreviewController
            controller.movieURL = videoRecorded
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code right now. There are a lot of complaints from Xcode and it doesn't make sense as Im not passing the videoRecorded from the fileOutput function into the segue override function.

I know to create a segue and pass data into another view controller I do something like

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if segue.identifier == "showCapture_Segue" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! CameraPreviewController
            controller.movieURL = videoRecorded
        }
    }
```

But I'm not sure how this integrates with my AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate. How can I do this? Thanks!

Edit:

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController {
    var outputURL: URL!
    func startRecording() {

        if movieOutput.isRecording == false {

            let connection = movieOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)
            if (connection?.isVideoOrientationSupported)! {
                connection?.videoOrientation = currentVideoOrientation()
            }

            if (connection?.isVideoStabilizationSupported)! {
                connection?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto
            }

            let device = activeInput.device
            if (device.isSmoothAutoFocusSupported) {
                do {
                    try device.lockForConfiguration()
                    device.isSmoothAutoFocusEnabled = false
                    device.unlockForConfiguration()
                } catch {
                    print("Error setting configuration: \(error)")
                }

            }

            //EDIT2: And I forgot this
            outputURL = tempURL()
            movieOutput.startRecording(to: outputURL, recordingDelegate: self)

        }
        else {
            stopRecording()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How is `videoRecorded` in the same scope? They are separate functions

Comment: @George_E I agree. As I mentioned it makes no sense as written. Im not sure how to integrate that prepare function. Thats part of the question.

Comment: The function is correct. Just make `videoRecorded` a global variable. That should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare as instance value

```
class CameraViewController {

   var videoRecorded:URL?

}
```

//

```
extension CameraViewController: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate{
 func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
    let destinationVC = PreviewViewController()
    if (error != nil) {
        print("Error recording movie: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
          self.videoRecorded = outputURL as! URL
    }
    outputURL = nil    }
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if segue.identifier == "showCapture_Segue" {
        let controller = segue.destination as! CameraPreviewController
        controller.movieURL = self.videoRecorded
    }
}
}
```

//

```
class CameraPreviewController {

   var movieURL:URL?

}
```

//

```
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCapture_Segue", sender: nil)
```

Comment: how do I use the controller.movieURL in the CameraPreviewController? I know I have to instantiate it there as well. What type should it be?

Comment: should be  **var movieURL:URL?**

Comment: in both **CameraViewController ** and **CameraPreviewController** you should declare that var same signature as assign it to the nextVC variable

Comment: So in CameraPreviewController, I have var movieURL:URL? . Then I want to use it with guard let playbackURL = URL(movieURL) else {return} . But it gives an error : Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: movieURL is of URL type , you can't make it in argument of URL

Comment: Im just learning swift so I think Im getting confused with all optionals and unwrapping them and variable types. Do you mind specifying in your answer exactly how each variable is defined and used in both the CameraViewController and CameraPreviewController classes?

Comment: hmm its building and not erroring out but its not performing the segue. Check out how I am instantiating and then writing to the outputURL in the startRecording function I added to the question. Do I need to write to the videoRecordedURL instead here?

Comment: see edit , run perform in button action or whereever you want